# A comma before the noun when using coordinate adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation

I have recently had multiple people, all of whom have back grounds in writing and ought to know the rules of punctuation, try to convince me that there should be a comma between a second coordinate adjective and the noun it modifies in a sentence. So instead of "It was a giant, ugly vase." they claim it would be correct to write "It was a giant, ugly, vase." This drives me nuts and I'm convinced it's incorrect. Is this EVER the correct way to write a sentence?

Comment: "This drives me nuts and I'm convinced it's incorrect." Maintain the rage! It's ridiculous to have a comma before the noun. People overthink this stuff. It would be awful to have to read commas like that.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, this combination is found commonly in the literature and can be examined ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=giant+ugly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgiant%20ugly%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgiant%20ugly%3B%2Cc0)). Of course, the result is valid for all adjectives and it is as you say: there should not ever be a comma after the last ajective. However, the comma between the coordinate adjectives is sometimes not used. Out of 50 cases or so not a single one showed a comma after the last adjective.

*A few examples*

- Boy looked at the giant, ugly, violent man.
- you evil, giant, ugly mutant Tyrannosaurus Rex!”
- like a giant ugly metal rock.
- But no, it looked like a giant, ugly, flying slug.
- You can't have some giant ugly freak standing behind me, you know?
- most probably indeed, into some giant, ugly, hungry insect.
- ... dinosaurs, and how the giant ugly nameless horrors are just sitting around on their tentacles,

Comment: Yes, I have seen people omit the comma before. But never add one before the noun! So I was really confused at having two separate people tell me there should be a comma there...